# Not find dynamic html element on .load() in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have Open Dynamic HTML Page (HTML element create on run time on this Page) on .load() in JQuery. like below Syntax

```
$("#Tagetdivision").load("../xyz.htm", function (){});
```

but now problem is that i can't access run time Generated HTML elements on this function. mean it is not bind yet on Page. so can`t use it. so how can i use this concept.

Comment: You need to use the callback method `$("#Tagetdivision").load("../xyz.htm", function (){ //Find here});`

Comment: will you describe bit a more ? or example

Comment: I use this but dynamic element not find here..page controls find but not dynamic element(which is generated on run time).

Comment: Is Tagetdivision exists in your code? do alert($("#Tagetdivision").length)...

Comment: yes. Tagetdivision is exists..alert return length : 1

Comment: Are you sure you're doing it how Satpal suggested? This should work correctly assuming the file is loaded: `$("#Tagetdivision").load("../xyz.htm", function (){ $(".yourItem").doSomthing() });`

Comment: The function which bind HTML element on Dynamic page is call after load() callback function. so element is not bind on load() callback function. so i not find element on load() callback function.

Comment: Are you trying to attach an event handler, or find the element? What your asking doesn't make a lot of sense at the moment?

Comment: I have to find element that is created on dynamic HTML page using $('#Targettype').html('HTML Content'); in method and this dynamic page is open on another page with .load() using Jquery. but on .load() can't find this element.

Comment: solve it by `$("#Tagetdivision").load("../xyz.htm", function (){ $(".yourItem").doSomthing() });`  Thanks @DBS